# Possible including users own class?

Tags: c++

Given is a programm Prog1, two libraries Lib1 and Lib2
Lib2 is communicating with Lib1 and Prog1 with Lib1. And Prog1 with Lib2 via Lib1.
Lib2 contains a XLib event loop...
And currently I've made a callback, that Prog1 can get the event messages.

To become more user friendly handling I'm thinking about a (predefined?) user class, which holds as member function e.g. Mouse_Click(), or Mouse_DblClick. And of course each XLib window has its own 'event class'...

But I have no idea how to include/connect/link this to Lib2 (via Lib1).
Ok, one thought was to make a serialized class, but, if possible, I want to hold it in the RAM.

Is that even possible?

Greeting 
Earlbite

EDIT----------------------------

```
    //cEeventLoop.cpp
    #include Lib2.h

    ClassLib2 *mClassLib2
    // Check events
    while(...){
     mClassLib2->mEventCallback(...);
    }

    //Lib2.h
    #include "cEventLoop.cpp"
    class ClassLib2{
     EventCallback mEventCallback;
     SetEvent_Callback(EventCallback vCallback){
      this->mEventCallBack = vCallback;
     }
    }

    //Lib1 has an interface to Lib2 for Prog1

    //Prog1
    #include "Lib1.h"
    ClassLib1 mClassLib1;

    void My_Event_Function(...){
     switch(...){
      case ...:
       //...
     }
    }

    main(){
    mClassLib1.SetEvent_Callback(My_Event_Function);
    }
```

So now I'm wondering if it is possible to give Prog1 a class with member functions (e.g. Mouse_Click(), or Mouse_DblClick()), where cEventLoop.cpp is using these functions instead of mClassLib2->mEventCallback(...); .
And of course each XLib window should have its own "Prog1 event class"...

HTH to understand

Comment: Show code, may be abstract code, how it works now, at how you want it to work. Without that your question is very unclear.